# Bitmap from TextView (getDrawingCache) always null

Tags: android, view

I am trying to extract the bitmap associated to the displayed TextView instance, but it always returns a null value. What Am I doing wrong? Should I use textview.draw(canvas) instead?

```
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    textview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    textview.buildDrawingCache();        
    Bitmap bmp = textview.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: This will work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560882/call-to-getdrawingcache-fails-on-api-8-everytime

Comment: @userSeven7s it will work only when we give a value for _width_ and _height_ attributes only. If we use attribute value like **wrap_content**, that is not working.

Comment: @AnujAroshA No. My view too was `wrap_content`ed. You should get the view's height and width after its inflated. Where do you do it? I recommend the `onFinishInflate()` or later in the activity life cycle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this before getting drawing cache it will solve  the problem

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
```

and then `getDrawingCache()` will return a bitmap and draw that bitmap on your canvas.

and if you are using bitmaps in your app prefer to clear them from memory by calling recycle() method on them so that bitmap get cleared from the memory for your safe side to avoid outOfMemoryException

Comment: This worked for me. Can you explain the reason for this?

Comment: @aysonje this is simulating the rendering pass on the view.

Answer (score 7):

Android has a maximum drawing cache size.  If the drawing cache would be bigger than that, getDrawingCache() returns null.  See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046766/android-drawing-cache).

You can find a workaround in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272859/getting-the-pixel-color-value-of-a-point-on-an-android-view-that-includes-a-bitma).

Answer (score 1):

```
view.getDrawingCache();
```

should be:

```
textview.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Of course, my mistake while writing the post. Anyway, it's still the same question, with a null value (and not a NullPointerException)