# Android get color under touchpoint

Tags: android, image-processing

How can I get the color of the image under the couch point in an imageview?

I have this code so far:

```
String image_overlay = 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + 
    s(R.string.APP_NAME) + "/overlay.jpg";
String visible_image = 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + 
    s(R.string.APP_NAME) + "/visible.jpg";

ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.visible_image);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(visible_image);
image.setImageBitmap(bm);

ImageView overlayimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.colormap_overlay);
Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_overlay);
overlayimage.setAlpha(0);
overlayimage.setImageBitmap(bm2);

final LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pageimageview);
parent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    // Get the color of the transparent layer under the touch point here
    // Send an intent with the color to do something based on the color touched
    return true;
  }
});
```

But I don't see any methods for MotionEvent that return a color. Specifically, I want the touch point "color" of a transparent layer (see the code above).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the pixel color value of a point on an Android View that includes a Bitmap-backed Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272859/getting-the-pixel-color-value-of-a-point-on-an-android-view-that-includes-a-bitm)