# Getting the color of a point on the screen

Tags: android, android-view

Ok, I'm not sure if it's at all possible, but is there a way to determine the color of a certain point on the screen? I'm using an onTouchEvent and I want to know the color where the user touched. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272859/getting-the-pixel-color-value-of-a-point-on-an-android-view-that-includes-a-bitm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used getDrawingCache on the view and then getPixel on the bitmap with the coordinates received in the onTouchEvent function.