# How to get the pixel value of the display in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was looking for a way how to extract the pixel value (RGB) of a selected (x,y) from my screen

(My display countains many images, not only the background)

thanks

Comment: The solutions is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272859/getting-the-pixel-color-value-of-a-point-on-an-android-view-that-includes-a-bitm

Comment: i have already checked it, but i didn't find how to get the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need the root container of your activity. Suppose xml of your activity looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <!-- All your stuff-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the activity find the root and using `jkhouw1` method get `Bitmap` which has method `getPixel`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(container);
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(100, 100);
    int r = Color.red(pixel);
    int b = Color.blue(pixel);
    int g = Color.green(pixel);
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: this method returns a null value in the variable pixel, any idea why ?

Comment: @user3501635 hm, are you sure `getPixel` returns null? Actually it can't return null.