# Changing the background of a view to match the color of the album art

Tags: android, background-color, albumart

Hello so im working on a Music Player for android and i wanted help on making the background color the same as the album art of the playing song kind of like Sony Walkman.So can somebody please show  how can it be done or at least get me on track on how it should be done.

I started Android recently so go easy on Me,and sorry for bad english

Comment: how are you going decide which pixel of the image is to be chosen for the background color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272859/getting-the-pixel-color-value-of-a-point-on-an-android-view-that-includes-a-bitm

these links will help you hopefully.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response i want the dominant color of the image to be chosen for background and thanks Awais for the links i will check them out

Answer (score 3):

You can use the v7 palette support library. It includes the **Palette** class, which lets you extract prominent colors from an image.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

**Example**

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
```

**Activity or fragment**

```
public void updatePlayerBar(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
            if (swatch == null) swatch = palette.getMutedSwatch(); // Sometimes vibrant swatch is not available
            if (swatch != null) {
                // Set the background color of the player bar based on the swatch color
                mContent.setBackgroundColor(swatch.getRgb());

                // Update the track's title with the proper title text color
                mTitle.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());

                // Update the artist name with the proper body text color
                mArtist.setTextColor(swatch.getBodyTextColor());
            }
        }
    });
}
```