# Get Bitmap from ImageView in Android L

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview

I want to get `Bitmap` from `ImageView`. I have used following code, but `getDrawable()` returns null. How to get whole `Bitmap` from `ImageView`.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
if (mImageViewer.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageViewer.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
} else {
    Drawable d = mImageViewer.getDrawable();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    d.draw(canvas);
}
storeImage(bitmap,"final.jpeg");
```

Comment: Your code should work, make sure your image view has a drawable, if you're setting the image using setBackground use setBitmap instead

Comment: You can check this answer of [How to convert whole ImageView to Bitmap?.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626338/2289835)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: how to convert whole ImageView to Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715044/android-how-to-convert-whole-imageview-to-bitmap)

Answer (score 38):

If you just want the Bitmap from a ImageView the following code may work for you:-

> `Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Try having the image in all drawable qualities folders (drawable-hdpi/drawable-ldpi etc.)

Could be that the emulator or device your using has a different density and is trying to pull images from another folder.

If you are using an extension in your image other than .png, .jpg, or .gif, It might not recognize other extension types. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: returns null ... everytime

Comment: do you have images in the mentioned folders ?

Comment: only in drawable folder

Comment: can you paste the same image in all the folders and try ?

Comment: still same pasted in all the folders

Comment: what's getting null imageview or bitmap ?

Comment: i m gettng bitmap null

Comment: @Maveňツ do onething, call this on post method of your image view

Answer (score 24):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717173/2003986), just do it like this:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: this doesn't work perfectly all the time, usually give Canvas: trying to use recycled bitmap

Comment: This solution along with this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566758/bitmap-from-textview-getdrawingcache-always-null) worked for me:

imageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
imageView.layout(0, 0, imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight());

Comment: getDrawingCache() is depricated

Answer (score 13):

**For Kotlin:**

simply write this code to get the bitmap from an ImageView

```
imageview.invalidate()
val drawable = imageview.drawable
val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap()
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to get bitmap from Glide loaded image then this will help you

```
 Drawable dr = ((ImageView) imView).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bmp =  ((GlideBitmapDrawable)dr.getCurrent()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a picture of the ImagView and convert it to a string to send to the server

```
    ImageView   ivImage1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.img_add1_send );
    getStringImage( ( ( BitmapDrawable ) ivImage1.getDrawable( ) ).getBitmap( ) ),



public String getStringImage(Bitmap bm){
    ByteArrayOutputStream ba=new ByteArrayOutputStream(  );
    bm.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,ba );
    byte[] by=ba.toByteArray();
    String encod= Base64.encodeToString( by,Base64.DEFAULT );
    return encod;
}
```