# Bitmap saved on sd card like black image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-sdcard

I am trying to save bitmap to sd cart, but it saved like black image.
This code shows like I am creating bitmap

```
    mStoryView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mStoryView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mStoryView.getDrawingCache());
    mStoryView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    result = ImageUtil.saveStoryImage(this,result);
```

On this step bitmap looks good ( I set it on background view).

```
 public static Bitmap saveStoryImage(Context context, Bitmap result) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "test.png");
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        boolean b = result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

After that I go to my sd card ondevice and saw black image.
What is the problem?

Comment: look answer at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489000/save-view-like-bitmap-i-only-get-black-screen

Comment: did you solved your problem?